# ListView после пролистывания перестает реагировать на нажатия (Xamarin Android)

Tags: android, listview, xamarin, adapter

После отрисовки `ListView` все элементы нажимаются как надо. Но если пролистать вниз, затем обратно наверх (или в любом другом порядке) - какие-то из элементов перестают реагировать на нажатия `ImageView` `CompleteView`. То есть делегат `CompleteView.Click` изменяет какой-то другой элемент списка либо вообще не срабатывает.
Прилагаю код Адаптера `ListView`

[image: Скриншот ListView]

```
public class ViewHolder : Java.Lang.Object
    {
        public TextView TaskName { get; set; }
        public TextView ProgressBar { get; set; }
        public TextView DeadLine { get; set; }
        public ImageView CompleteView { get; set; }
        public ImageView TaskColor { get; set; }
        public ImageView Indicator { get; set; }
        public ImageView Star { get; set; }
    }

    public class MainListAdapter : BaseAdapter<Task>   //АДАПТЕР ДЛЯ ОСНОВОГО СПИСКА
    {
        List<Task> tasks;
        Activity activity;

        public MainListAdapter(Activity act, List<Task> tasks)
        {
            activity = act;
            this.tasks = tasks;
        }

        public override int Count
        {
            get { return tasks.Count; }
        }

        public override Task this[int position]
        {
            get { return tasks[position]; }
        }

        public override long GetItemId(int position)
        {
            return position;
        }

        public void RemoveView(int position)
        {
            tasks.RemoveAt(position);
            NotifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            var view = convertView;
            ViewHolder Holder;

            if (view == null)
            {
                Holder = new ViewHolder();
                view = activity.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.TaskItem, null);
                Holder.TaskName = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.TaskName);
                Holder.ProgressBar = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.TaskProgressBar);
                Holder.DeadLine = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.DeadlineView);
                Holder.CompleteView = view.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.CompleteView);
                Holder.TaskColor = view.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.TaskColor);
                Holder.Indicator = view.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.DeadLineBar);
                Holder.Star = view.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.RateStar);
                view.Tag = Holder;
            }
            else Holder = (ViewHolder)view.Tag;



            Holder.TaskName.Text = tasks[position].name;
            if (tasks[position].rated)
            {
                Holder.TaskName.TextSize = 56;
                Holder.TaskName.SetTypeface(Typeface.CreateFromAsset(Application.Context.Assets, "OpenSans-Light.ttf"), TypefaceStyle.Normal);
                Holder.Star.Alpha = 255;
            }
            else
            {
                Holder.TaskName.TextSize = 24;
                Holder.TaskName.SetTypeface(Typeface.CreateFromAsset(Application.Context.Assets, "OpenSans-Regular.ttf"), TypefaceStyle.Normal);
                Holder.Star.Alpha = 0;
            }

            Holder.TaskColor.SetImageDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.ParseColor(tasks[position].category.colorID)));
            if (tasks[position].completed) Holder.TaskColor.ImageAlpha = 80;
            else Holder.TaskColor.ImageAlpha = 255;

            DateTime D = tasks[position].deadline;
            Holder.DeadLine.SetTypeface(Typeface.CreateFromAsset(Application.Context.Assets, "OpenSans-Regular.ttf"), TypefaceStyle.Bold);
            Holder.DeadLine.Text = "До ";
            switch (D.DayOfWeek)
            {
                case DayOfWeek.Monday: Holder.DeadLine.Text += "понедельника, "; break;
                case DayOfWeek.Tuesday: Holder.DeadLine.Text += "вторника, "; break;
                case DayOfWeek.Wednesday: Holder.DeadLine.Text += "среды, "; break;
                case DayOfWeek.Thursday: Holder.DeadLine.Text += "четверга, "; break;
                case DayOfWeek.Friday: Holder.DeadLine.Text += "пятницы, "; break;
                case DayOfWeek.Saturday: Holder.DeadLine.Text += "субботы, "; break;
                case DayOfWeek.Sunday: Holder.DeadLine.Text += "воскресенья, "; break;
            }
            Holder.DeadLine.Text += D.Day;
            switch (D.Month)
            {
                case 1: Holder.DeadLine.Text += " Января"; break;
                case 2: Holder.DeadLine.Text += " Февраля"; break;
                case 3: Holder.DeadLine.Text += " Марта"; break;
                case 4: Holder.DeadLine.Text += " Апреля"; break;
                case 5: Holder.DeadLine.Text += " Мая"; break;
                case 6: Holder.DeadLine.Text += " Июня"; break;
                case 7: Holder.DeadLine.Text += " Июля"; break;
                case 8: Holder.DeadLine.Text += " Августа"; break;
                case 9: Holder.DeadLine.Text += " Сентября"; break;
                case 10: Holder.DeadLine.Text += " Октября"; break;
                case 11: Holder.DeadLine.Text += " Ноября"; break;
                case 12: Holder.DeadLine.Text += " Декабря"; break;
            }

            if (D.Date <= DateTime.Today && !tasks[position].completed) Holder.Indicator.SetBackgroundColor(Color.ParseColor("#ffff4054"));
            else Holder.Indicator.SetBackgroundColor(Color.ParseColor("#ff585c75"));

            if (tasks[position].completed)
            {
                Holder.CompleteView.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.Completed);
            }
            else
            {
                Holder.CompleteView.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.RadioButton);
            }

            Holder.CompleteView.Click += delegate
            {
                if (tasks[position].completed)
                {
                    Holder.CompleteView.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.RadioButton);
                    tasks[position].completed = false;
                    Holder.TaskColor.ImageAlpha = 255;
                    if (D.Date <= DateTime.Today) Holder.Indicator.SetBackgroundColor(Color.ParseColor("#ffff4054"));
                    else Holder.Indicator.SetBackgroundColor(Color.ParseColor("#ff585c75"));

                    ScaleAnimation A = new ScaleAnimation(1.0f, (float)((615 * tasks[position].GetProgress()) / Holder.ProgressBar.Width), 1.0f, 1.0f);
                    A.Duration = 400;
                    A.FillAfter = true;
                    A.FillEnabled = true;
                    A.AnimationEnd += (sender1, e1) =>
                    {
                        Holder.ProgressBar.ClearAnimation();
                        Holder.ProgressBar.SetWidth((int)((tasks[position].GetProgress()) * 615) + 5);
                    };
                    Holder.ProgressBar.StartAnimation(A);
                }
                else
                {
                    Holder.CompleteView.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.Completed);
                    tasks[position].completed = true;
                    Holder.TaskColor.ImageAlpha = 90;
                    Holder.Indicator.SetBackgroundColor(Color.ParseColor("#ff585c75"));

                    ScaleAnimation A = new ScaleAnimation(1.0f, 615f / Holder.ProgressBar.Width, 1.0f, 1.0f);
                    A.Duration = 400;
                    A.FillAfter = true;
                    A.FillEnabled = true;
                    A.AnimationEnd += (sender1, e1) =>
                    {
                        Holder.ProgressBar.ClearAnimation();
                        Holder.ProgressBar.SetWidth(615);
                    };
                    Holder.ProgressBar.StartAnimation(A);
                }
            };

            Holder.TaskName.BringToFront();
            if (tasks[position].completed || tasks[position].GetProgress() == 1) Holder.ProgressBar.SetWidth(615);
            else Holder.ProgressBar.SetWidth((int)(615 * tasks[position].GetProgress()) + 5);
            Holder.CompleteView.RequestFocus();

            return view;
        }
```

Comment: Попробуйте `RecyclerView`

Comment: Переделал все на RecyclerView. Ничего не изменилось

Comment: Вы решили эту проблему?